# My program in C works all fine, but at the very end when I try to create a loop so it keeps repeating if the user wants, It doesnt seem to work

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.14159265

int main()
{
    int n;
    int fact=1;
    int i;
    char repeat;
    do{
    //part a
    printf("Please input a positive whole number value to be stored as 'n': ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n<0){
        printf("Improper value of n. Please input a positive whole number value to be stored as 'n': ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    //part b
    if (n>0){
        printf("n is now %d\n",n);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            fact=fact*i;
        }
        //printf("The factorial of %d is %d.\n",n,fact);
    }
    else{
        printf("The factorial of 0 is 1.\n");
    }
    //part c
    double approx = (pow((double)n,n)*exp(-n))*sqrt(((2*n)+(1/3))*pi);
    //printf("Approx is %lf",approx);
    //part d
    printf("%d! equals approximately %lf.\n",n,approx);
    printf("%d! is %d accurately.\n",n,fact);
    //part e
    double perror=((fact-approx)/(fact))*100;
    printf("The approximate value is off by %lf%%\n",perror);
    //part f
    printf("Would you like to restart with another value? Respond y or n: ");
    scanf("%c",&repeat);
    } while(repeat=='y');
    /*I was going to have the program restart if the user input "y" at the end of the program but I can't
    figure out why it isn't working.*/

    return 0;
}
```

I'm still very new to programming in C and am still learning the basics so any explanations are appreciated.
The only part that I have left to and haven't been able to figure out is as to why the do...while loop isn't working at the beginning and end of the code.

Comment: Unrelated: `perror` is already a function to print error messages. You should not use same name as standard library functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%c",&repeat);
```

You need a space before `%c` in order to consume the newline left by previous calls to `scanf`:

```
scanf(" %c",&repeat);
```

From https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf:

> **Conversions**
>
> c
>
> Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the
> maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to
> char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no
> terminating null byte is added). The usual skip of leading white space
> is suppressed. ***To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the
> format***.

Also, never trust the user and always initialize the variables before using `scanf`, otherwise you can end up reading uninitialized values (garbage) if it fails:

```
char repeat;
```

should be

```
char repeat = 'n';
```

or at least check the result of `scanf` and fill the variable with proper default values:

```
char repeat;
...
if (scanf(" %c",&repeat) != 1)
{
    repeat = 'n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! Can you explain this a little more to me? How exactly does the space make the difference between it working and not? Thank you again.

Comment: @Lemons you have an edit